# Type '"test"' cannot be used to index type 'T'

Tags: typescript

Any idea how this can be achieved?

```
function getTest<T>(): T["test"] {
    // ...
}
```

...or dynamically:

```
function getTest<T, U>(): T[U] {
    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler says `Type '“test”' cannot be used to index type 'T'`. I'm using TypeScript 2.4.2.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Note that for type inference to work, you'll need to pass a parameter to the function that uses one or more of the generic type parameters.

Otherwise, it will be inferred to `{}` or `any`.

---

For the first case:

```
function getTest<T, U extends {test: T}>(): T {}
```

For the second case:

```
function getTest<T, K extends keyof T>(): T[K] {}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! But what exactly does "extends keyof T" mean? As I understand, "keyof T" is just a list of strings, I wonder in what way it could be "extended"?

Comment: "extends" means a type with covariant relationship with `keyof T`. Practically, it means any string that's one of the keys of T.